# Formatting messages in Play application

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using Play Framework (2.3.2) in Java for developing a web application. The message language is the default English (en), so I have a file named `messages.en` in the `conf` directory of the application.

How do I write long messages in the file? My message consists of several sentences. One option is to write them all in a single line but then I have to scroll horizontally to read it. Also, how can I format a message by putting html tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate multiple lines with the `\` character

```
multiline.message=First line \
Second line
message.with.html=<b>Strong message</b>
```

The output for @Messages("multiline.message") will be:

```
First line Second line
```

HTML tags can be escaped with the helper object

```
@Html(Messages("message.with.html"))
```